# Create a thread for a method in a loop in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

In C#, I want to be able to call a method once per iteration of a loop, and create a thread for that method call. I want that thread to run concurrently with each other thread created by the loop. I want the thread to spawn when the method is called in the loop and I want the loop to continue to the next iteration of itself and immediately create the next thread. After the loop is finished running, I want to wait for all of the threads to finish.

I've heard of `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` but can't seem to wrap my head around it for this situation.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myObject obj = new myObject();
    obj.height = i;
    obj.width = i+a*b/c;
    var data = myMethod(obj);
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried, what problems are you having, what resources have you looked at on how to accomplish this, what do you and don't you understand about this topic in those resources?

Comment: `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach` would be better.

Comment: Sounds like the answer for you is Task Factory. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782519%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like what you are trying to implement manually is already created for you by .Net framework in the form of `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
{
    myObject obj = new myObject();
    obj.height = i;
    obj.width = i+a*b/c;

    var data = myMethod(obj);
});
```